# Parallel.For & getting the next free thread/worker

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following parallelised code. What I'm not sure of is how to set the workerIndex variable:

```
// Initializing Worker takes time & must be done before the actual work
Worker[] w = new Worker[3]; // I would like to limit the parallelism to 3
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  w[i] = new Worker();
...
element[] elements = GetArrayOfElements(); // elements.Length > 3
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOption();
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 3;
Parallel.For(0, elements.Length, options, i =>
{
  element e = elements[i];
  w[workerIndex].Work(e); // how to set "workerIndex"?
});
```

Is there some mechanism that says which worker thread id is free next?

Comment: How about `var workerIndex = i % w.Length`?

Comment: @major-mann - say that the item an index 2 takes hours to process but all other items are quick. You'll quickly have a situation where one thread is stuck processing item 2 and another thread picks up item 5.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If that is the case, then processing workers in parallel is certainly not what you should be doing...

Comment: @major-mann - the point was to exaggerate the timing so that you could hopefully see why something like `var workerIndex = i % w.Length` isn't appropriate. You don't know that each thread will always be assigned the 1st, 4th, 7th, etc items nor that each thread will complete the work in each iteration at the same time.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I see what you are saying now, and you are quite right.

Answer (score 0):

How about you just `new Worker()` in the `Parallel.For` loop, and add them to `w`  (you would need to change w to a concurrent list).

Possibly (if it is not too complex) move the contents of the `.Work(e)` method to the body of the loop, eliminating the need for the `Worker` class.

**Edit:**

If you change your `Worker` array to a `IEnumerable` (i.e. a `List<Worker>`) you can use [`.AsParallel()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel(v=vs.100).aspx) to make it parallel. Then you can use [.ForAll(worker -> worker.Work())](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383744(v=vs.100).aspx) to do the work in parallel. This would require you to pass the `element` into the worker through the constructor.

Comment: as mentioned in the code new Wroker takes time & must be done beforehand.

Comment: Updated with an other option.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Object pool pattern is best for you. You can write the code like this:

```
const int Limit = 3;
using (var pool = new QueueObjectPool<Worker>(a => new Worker(), Limit)) {
    element[] elements = GetArrayOfElements();
    var options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Limit };

    Parallel.For(0, elements.Length, options, i => {
        element e = elements[i];
        Worker worker = null;
        try {
            worker = pool.Acquire();
            worker.Work(e);
        } finally {
            pool.Release(worker);
        }
    });
}
```

During start every element will wait for available worker and only three workers will be initialized form beginning. Here is simplified queue base object pool implementation:

```
public sealed class QueueObjectPool<TObject> : IDisposable {
        private readonly Queue<TObject> _poolQueue;
        private readonly Func<QueueObjectPool<TObject>, TObject> _factory;
        private readonly int _capacity;
        private readonly SemaphoreSlim _throttler;
        public QueueObjectPool(Func<QueueObjectPool<TObject>, TObject> factory, int capacity) {
            _factory = factory;
            _capacity = capacity;
            _throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: capacity, maxCount: capacity);
            _poolQueue = CreatePoolQueue();
        }
        public TObject Acquire() {
            _throttler.Wait();

            lock (_poolQueue) {
                return _poolQueue.Dequeue();
            }
        }
        public void Release(TObject poolObject) {
            lock (_poolQueue) {
                _poolQueue.Enqueue(poolObject);
            }

            _throttler.Release();
        }
        private Queue<TObject> CreatePoolQueue() {
            var queue = new Queue<TObject>(_capacity);
            int itemsLeft = _capacity;

            while (itemsLeft > 0) {
                TObject queueObject = _factory(this);
                queue.Enqueue(queueObject);
                itemsLeft -= 1;
            }

            return queue;
        }
        public void Dispose() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

This code is for demo purposes. In real work it is better to use async/await based logic which is easily achieved using `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` and you can replace Parallel.For with simple loop.